# Minimum circuitry for robust operation of the "new" ATtinys (1614) with Optiboot

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, avr, schematics

I have spent hours now trying to catch up on the replacements for the old ATtiny's, there does not seem to be a robust (meaning, with protections that we could find in an UNO or Mega for example) schematic for the ATtiny14 when the use case is the following:

- Board, not breadboard
- [MegaTinyCore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/megaTinyCore) (huge thanks to Dr.Azzy)
- Programming of Optiboot using one of the programmers a) a modified USB-Serial cable for SerialUPDI or b) an Arduino programmed with the jtag2updi sketch
- To program the board, power cycle it - Optiboot will wait for 8s for a new program to be uploaded over the UART before starting the firmware, so no need for auto-reset

What I have so far is this, but I'm not sure if this is actually reliable or not. I don't think the diode I'm used to putting on RESET for example would work. Also, is the ATtiny14 sensitive to ESD? It doesn't seem to say in the datasheet.

[image]

To burn the bootloader, I leave the 2x3 header without jumpers and connect GND + UPDI/RST# to the [SerialUPDI device](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/AVR-Guidance/blob/master/UPDI/jtag2updi.md). After burning the bootloader, I replace the jumper between UPDI/RST# and the pullup+ (optional?) capacitor. I expect to be able to just power cycle and hit "program over COM" in Arduino to exploit the newly burnt Optiboot.

Am I missing anything? I would like to get everything right before purchasing the components for the breadboard.

Comment: `protections that we could find in an UNO` ... UNO has no protection circuitry